# fail2ban stop working ambigiously

Tags: monitoring, fail2ban

Its has been 3 months since monitoring. And nature of fail2ban that I observe is that it stop blocking ips after few days of busy schedule. Then I use to restart it and it again start working, blocking IP. For few months things goes this way but after few months, fail2ban not block IP even after restarting. Then I have to do fresh installation of fail2ban and then It again start blocking.

Can anyone tell reason for such nature of fail2ban?

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to know what is happening withou any config file or log. Anyway, that kind of behavior can be because of a clock sync problem.

I don't know if you structure could be: one machine generating logs of the services and other machine with fail2ban reading it and banning. Or a host machine with fail2ban and the services in docker containers. In these case of scenarios, the date should be sync, that includes the timezone. Maybe after restarting your server is synchronizing your clock and changing the date... I don't know. Is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but fail2ban is running on same machine as on which service is running or logs are generating. So there are no containers or host guest relationship. And that's why it cannot be clock sync problem.

Comment: Ok. Put your config here. What service is failing? only one? all of them? what filter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban removes the banned hosts from your list according to the time set in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime = 3600
```

No ban on fail2ban is permanent (unless done by some configuration modification), so if you reboot with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart
```

all banned ips will automatically receive an unban.

For you to restart the service without losing the list of banned ips, type

```
sudo fail2ban-client reload
```